# What's the difference between AzureAD scheme and OpendId aad scheme?

Tags: azure-active-directory, identityserver4

I'm working on IdentityServer4, I used Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI for Microsoft login and I see there is also OpenIdConnectExtension(AddOpenIdConnect("aad", ...)) for Microsoft login.

They both work the same in a client, but not when I set up an instance of IdentityServer like [IS4 demo.io](https://demo.identityserver.io/). Because if I use AzureAD.UI the idp is "AzureAD" and if I use OpenIdConnect extension the idp is "aad". Are they the same?

Answer (score 0):

They're different packages. The [former](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI/) depens on the [latter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/).